# Getting nest pin without a UI

Tags: nest-api

I have a web client that talks to a .NET webservice for data and control of various household systems.  I want to expose nest thermostat control in the web client via the .NET webservice.  I understand the typical auth process requires "users" to authenticate a client using the provided "works with nest" page to get a code and then use that code to get a token.  In my case the .NET webservice is the client and there is no user or UI to allow a user to "accept" and thus I need a way to get the auth token (or pin) without pushing a webpage in front of a user? Is this possible?  thanks

UPDATE:
I manually went through the process of generating a token and discovered the expires number to be rather large (10 years).  Given that is there any reason I can't just use that token in my .NET app with all future rest calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token will only allow you to access the approving account, so if this application is for your personal use, then yeah, just hard code the token.

If you .NET service can handle an oAuth callback (A little confused about how you would have a webservice that can't serve HTML) then you can enter the callback URI into your client settings on developer.nest.com and the PIN will be returned directly to the service for you. The callback URI must start with `https://` or `http://localhost` though.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, if you're using a web service, specifically a SOAP service, then XML will be returned on the callback, not HTML. In the case of the nest API, JSON is returned.

In the case of oAuth, it's done on the lower level protocol of http using headers, URIs and the like.  Here is the link to the standard:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849